# Create object of objects from arrays

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have two arrays in JavaScript:

```
a = [2, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15]
```

and

```
b = ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06"]
```

I want to turn this into an object of objects, like so:

```
ts = {
  {
    value: 2,
    time: "2022-01-01"
  },
  {
    value: 5,
    time: "2022-01-02"
  },
  {
    value: 8,
    time: "2022-01-03"
  },
  {
    value: 10,
    time: "2022-01-04"
  },
  {
    value: 12,
    time: "2022-01-05"
  },
  { 
    value: 15,
    time: "2022-01-06"
  }   
}
```

I have looked at the `forEach` method and the `reduce` method, e.g. from https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-create-object-from-two-arrays , but I am struggling. **Edit:** my attempt was along the lines of:

```
const ts = {};
a.forEach((a_value, index) => {
  ts.value[index] = a_value[index];
});
```

Comment: you can put what you have tried so far

Comment: you can do this with 1 map function on either array and using the index of the callback you can access the other array and then create each object element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop will work if both lists are the same size.

```js
let a = [2, 5, 8, 10, 12, 15]
let b = ["2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-03", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-05", "2022-01-06"]

let ts = []

for (let idx in a) {
  ts.push({value: a[idx],
    time: b[idx]})
}

console.log(ts)
```